# How to fold an email header with long email addresses according to RFC 5322?

Tags: email, header, rfc5322

Assume that an email has the following header field:

```
To: =?utf-8?q?Foo_Bar?= <1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234@abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi.com>
```

Is there a way to fold the header

1. in full accordance with [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
2. such that the email is still accepted by commonly used MTAs, and
3. no line exceeds a length of 78 characters?

I am aware that the hard limit on line length is 998 chars, but I wonder if it is possible to also fulfill all SHOULD-requirements. If I understand the Augmented Backus-Naur Form

```
domain-literal  =   [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dtext) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]

dtext           =   %d33-90 /          ; Printable US-ASCII
                    %d94-126 /         ;  characters not including
                    obs-dtext          ;  "[", "]", or "\"
```

in [section 3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) correctly, one can insert folding whitespace into domain literals, and the following should be valid:

```
To: =?utf-8?q?Foo_Bar?=
 <1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234@abcdefgh
 iabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi.com>
```

However, this is rejected by recent versions of postfix and exim:

```
501:  <1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234@abcdefgh: '>' missing at end of address
```

Either both MTAs are broken (which seems highly unlikely), or my interpretation of the RFC is wrong.

**Addendum in case someone runs into similar problems:**

Before posting the question, I actually tried to fold at `@` and `.` as shown in the RFC-conformant [example by jstedfast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36206005/6107662), but got the same error message. As it turns out, this was not the fault of the MTA but of the SMTP client library I used, which extracted the recipient addresses from the header for generating `RCPT TO:` commands for SMTP and failed to filter out the line breaks.

Comment: I had a feeling the error might have been the SMTP client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to break the domain across line boundaries in the middle of a domain (which is what you did), only before/after the domain.

RFC5322 says you SHOULD NOT break around the `@`, but that doesn't mean MAY NOT.

```
angle-addr      =   [CFWS] "<" addr-spec ">" [CFWS] /
                    obs-angle-addr

addr-spec       =   local-part "@" domain

local-part      =   dot-atom / quoted-string / obs-local-part

domain          =   dot-atom / domain-literal / obs-domain

domain-literal  =   [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dtext) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]

dtext           =   %d33-90 /          ; Printable US-ASCII
                    %d94-126 /         ;  characters not including
                    obs-dtext          ;  "[", "]", or "\"

atext           =   ALPHA / DIGIT /    ; Printable US-ASCII
                    "!" / "#" /        ;  characters not including
                    "$" / "%" /        ;  specials.  Used for atoms.
                    "&" / "'" /
                    "*" / "+" /
                    "-" / "/" /
                    "=" / "?" /
                    "^" / "_" /
                    "`" / "{" /
                    "|" / "}" /
                    "~"

atom            =   [CFWS] 1*atext [CFWS]

dot-atom-text   =   1*atext *("." 1*atext)

dot-atom        =   [CFWS] dot-atom-text [CFWS]

specials        =   "(" / ")" /        ; Special characters that do
                    "<" / ">" /        ;  not appear in atext
                    "[" / "]" /
                    ":" / ";" /
                    "@" / "\" /
                    "," / "." /
                    DQUOTE
```

So, if we expand the definitions and apply it to your example, what we get is (each token on its own line to avoid the need to scroll horizontally):

```
[CFWS]
"<"
[CFWS] 
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234"
[CFWS]
"@"
[CFWS] 
"abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi"
"."
"com"
[CFWS]
">"
```

Wherever you see `[CFWS]` is where the spec technically allows you to insert a line break.

So an example way to break your `To` header would be this:

```
To: =?utf-8?q?Foo_Bar?=
 <
 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
 @
 abcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghiabcdefghi.com
 >
```

Any RFC-compliant address parser will need to handle that.

(Self-promotion here, but [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit)'s address parser handles this ;-)

Comment: The `domain-literal` form requires "[" and "]". It's only used for IP addresses, e.g. `hello@[127.0.0.1]`. My reading of the grammar only allows for folding whitespace around "." because of `obs-domain`. RFC5322 states that "these syntactic forms MUST NOT be generated".